# create table in hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to create hive table with this syntax :

```
create table table_name as orc as select * from table1 partitioned by (Acc_date date).
```

I am getting error. My requirement is to create table using select statement and append the table when the next load happens.

I am trying to replicate this spark command:

```
df1.distinct().repartition("acc_date").write.mode("append").partitionBy("acc_date").format("parquet").saveAsTable("schema.table_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a two step process.

1. Create the partition table as you want.
2. Insert data into it.

Details
1.sql may be like this -

```
create table if not exists table_name
(Col1 int, col2...)
partition (acc_date date)
Stored as orc ;
```

2. Insert will be like below. Make sure partition column is the last column in select clause.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true; 
 set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
Insert into table_name  partition (Acc_date ) 
Select col1,col2... acc_date from table1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this...I am putting my hive sql's in a script and running...how do I comment the create table statement?

Comment: You can use `create table if not exists...`

Comment: Thank you very much @Koushik Roy...I got the result

Comment: Did above answer the question?