# null values in partition column after data load in hive

Tags: hive

I am a creating a table in hive and inserting data based on the partition column. The data is loading but when query the table and try to find the distinct of partition column values then I am getting nulls.

Table creation syntax: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table 1 (column1 INT, column2 String, Column3 String) PARTITIONED BY (ACC_D date) STORED AS orc;

Inserting data into the Table:

INSERT INTO TABLE  Table 1 PARTITION (ACC_D)
SELECT DISTINCT
*
FROM
Schema.Sales;

I am using these properties after create and before inserting into the table

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=TRUE;

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

Using these properties based on the answer from this post : [create table in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73918494/create-table-in-hive)

Comment: Can you spell out the column names in insert like this - `INSERT INTO TABLE Table 1 PARTITION (ACC_D) SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,col3, acc_d FROM Schema.Sales;` i think select * is providing wrong sequence of columns.

Comment: I think you are correct...The order is different, but then how do I correct the order for the select * from? cos when I create the final table the partition column will be the final column ( as we are explicitly do not mention the column name while creating a table)

Comment: Instead of selecting * from..I am manually selecting the columns, so lets see how it works